# Fix Record Lock issue or Record Not available

Tags: apex, trigger, asynchronous

I have a trigger on an Object called `SubscriptionProductCharges`.

we have another system that are updating `SubscriptionProductCharges` records in a batch of 1, which means if we update 5 records, then the trigger will fire every 5 times.

I am updating the opportunity record from that trigger.

**Issue** is opportunity record is locked with the first transaction of the trigger, but on second transaction record is not updating it firing error, I tried future but it will not work.

This problem can be solved with Queueableapex with FINALIZERS, but I am not sure if this issue will be fixed with that. please advice

Comment: If the batchsize = 1, then there will be 5 execute() method invocations, each a separate transaction so any locks done on Txn 1 will be released before Txn 2 starts. Perhaps you have async processes kicked off by an `execute()` that is locking records when Txn 2 starts

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a record-locking issue when updating the opportunity record from the trigger on SubscriptionProductCharges. This can happen when multiple transactions try to update the same record concurrently. One possible solution is to use the `Database.update` method with the **allOrNone** parameter set to **false**. This will allow partial updates and avoid throwing an exception when a record is locked.

Another possible solution is to use **Quableapex** with **FINALIZERS** to update the opportunity record asynchronously and handle any errors gracefully. You can create a class that implements the **Queueable** and **Finalizer** interfaces, and define the logic for updating the opportunity record in the execute method, and the logic for handling errors in the executeFinally method. Then, you can enqueue the class instance from the trigger using `System.enqueueJob`.

Example of how you can use Quableapex with FINALIZERS to update the opportunity record:

```
public class UpdateOpportunityQueueable implements Queueable, Finalizer {
    
    private Id oppId;

        public UpdateOpportunityQueueable(Id oppId) {
                this.oppId = oppId;
        }
        
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
                Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId];
                opp.Name = 'Updated by Queueable';
                update opp;
        }

        public void executeFinally(FinalizerContext context) {
                if (context.getResult() == FinalizerResult.FAILED) {
                        Exception ex = context.getException();
                        System.debug('Queueable job failed: ' + ex.getMessage());
                }
        }
}


trigger UpdateOpportunityTrigger on SubscriptionProductCharges (after update){
        for (SubscriptionProductCharges spc : Trigger.new) {
                Id oppId = spc.Opportunity__c;
                UpdateOpportunityQueueable uoq = new UpdateOpportunityQueueable(oppId);
                System.enqueueJob(uoq);
        }
}
```